# ZIP file specification encryption header

Tags: file, zip, file-format

I am reading the zip file [specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) and there is no explanation as to how the encryption header for a file in the archive is structured. The header order is like this:

> [local file header 1]
> [encryption header 1]
> [file data 1]
> [data descriptor 1]

After the local file header the specification says the following while skipping the encryption header part:

> Immediately following the local header for a file
> SHOULD be placed the compressed or stored data for the file.
> If the file is encrypted, the encryption header for the file
> SHOULD be placed after the local header and before the file
> data. The series of [local file header][encryption header]
> [file data][data descriptor] repeats for each file in the
> .ZIP archive.

I am searching for how this encryption header is structured because this specification does not explain it. Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*6.1 Traditional PKWARE Decryption*

...

*6.1.3 Each encrypted file has an extra 12 bytes stored at the start
of the data area defining the encryption header for that file.  The
encryption header is originally set to random values, and then
itself encrypted, using three, 32-bit keys.  The key values are
initialized using the supplied encryption password.  After each byte
is encrypted, the keys are then updated using pseudo-random number
generation techniques in combination with the same CRC-32 algorithm
used in PKZIP and described elsewhere in this document.*

...

The specification for the decryption header depends on the encryption algorithm used. There is an *Traditional PKWARE Encryption (standard)* but this is out of date and therefore a custom encryption/decryption should be used.

Answer (score 0):

`RAR 5.0 archive format` looks a good document at https://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm

You might find it helpful in the project `sharpcompress`:
https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/tree/master/src/SharpCompress/Common/Zip

Answer (score 0):

Following is a link to the specification for version 6.3.5. [zip version 6.3.5 specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-6.3.6.TXT).

Section 7.2.4 Decryption header record preceding compressed file data

Archive Decryption header and Decryption header are similar.

I didnt see where it mentioned the signature of Decryption header.

Section 4.2.1 Each record must have a signature that start with 'PK'.

Section 4.4.5 If compression method 99 is used, this signifies AE-x encryption marker. An AE-x header of size 11 will be stored in local file header extra field. The header has the id 0x9901.